# Proving a space is complete by assuming Cauchy sequences converge

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I had an interesting debate with some classmates on how to prove that a space is complete.

I went through the process of taking a Cauchy sequence, finding a candidate limit, and showing that the limit is both in the space and is the actual limit of the Cauchy sequence.

However, some of my classmates instead supposed that the Cauchy sequence converged to *something*, and proceeded to show that the limit is in the space.

Is their method correct? It seems odd to me to assume that the Cauchy sequence converges. I know we could use this to show that the space is closed, but we are *not* assuming that the ambient space is complete.

They argue that every Cauchy sequence converges in the completion of the metric space so it is no problem assuming that the Cauchy sequence converges: all that is left is to show that the limit belongs to the space. Is this a legitimate strategy for showing that a space is complete?

EDIT: More explicitly, to show a space $X$ is complete, can we say ``let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence that converges to $x$. It suffices to show $x\in X$?''

Comment: Sure, the ambient space must be complete and your space must be closed on it to have that the space is complete

Comment: Naive question (because my last analysis was decades ago):  do such completions always exist?

Comment: Every metric space does have a completion.

Comment: I guess my question is can we always assume that we are embedding a space in its completion?

For example, to show $X$ is complete, can we say ``let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence that converges to $x$. It suffices to show $x\in X$?''

Comment: We can not *always* assume embedding into a completion, not if we want to prove the [completion theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Completion_Theorem_(Metric_Space)) itself, for example. Instead of assuming a "something" it converges to the intrinsic approach is to turn suitable classes of Cauchy sequences into elements of the completion. But once the theorem is proved one can do what your classmates did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to figure out what exactly are they trying to do.

Every metric space $X$ has a completion $\overline X$, which is defined using equivalence class of Cauchy sequences.

In particular, if $\{x_n\}$ is the given Cauchy sequence, then the limit in the completion is .... $[\{x_n\}]$, the equivalence class in the completion.

One has the embedding 
$$\phi: X \to \overline X$$ 
given by $\phi(x) = [\{x, x, \cdots, x, \cdots\}]$ (the equivalence class of the constant Cauchy sequence), then to say that the limit is in $X$, it really means 
$$ [\{x_n\}] = [\{x, x, \cdots, x, \cdots\}]$$
in $\overline X$. Writing down the definition of the equivalence, it becomes:

> for all $\epsilon >0$, there is $N\in \mathbb N$ so that 
>   $$ |x_n - x|<\epsilon$$
>   for all $n\ge N$.

(it would be $|x_n - y_n|<\epsilon$ for two sequence in general, but now one of them is constant).

This is exactly the definition of the convergence of $\{x_n\}$ to $x$.

Thus your classmate is not wrong strictly speaking. However, it seems to be a pointless complications. What's more, I don't see how thinking this way would help guessing the limit.

Comment: Thank you for showing the equivalence of the convergence definition and the equivalence class one, that really helps! 

In our particular problem, it is a lot easier to show that the limit is in the space. My method of finding the candidate limit requires a little bit of extra work, but I guess it does give an explicit limit function. Since the problem was just to show that the space is complete, this method of using the completion of the space is definitely better. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Keep in mind the OP's approach, exactly as phrased ("it suffices to show that $x \in X$"), is not correct. With this approach you have to take the limit to be a sequence, not an element of $X$. And you don't show that the sequence is in $X$ - you show that it equals the image of an element of $X$. In the end you aren't saving any work because proving that the sequence is an image of an element of $X$ is exactly the same as showing that the sequence has a limit.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret I may be misunderstanding you, but shouldn't the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ be an element of $X$? Or did you mean that the image of the sequence $(x_n)$ under the embedding map needs to be the class of the constant Cauchy sequence given above by Arctic Char?

Comment: @Rem You need to show that $\phi((x_n)) = \phi((x))$, where $\phi((x))$ is in $\overline X$, not $X$. This is just a fancy way of saying that you need to show that $(x_n)$ converges to some $x \in X$ so it doesn't make the problem easier.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret I see. So we would still need to come up with a candidate limit no matter what.